# Tab Background change on selection

Tags: android, tabview

I need to set different Images as tab background on different states. I have set one image as background for default but how to switch to other one when tab is selected. Below is my code.

```
public class HelloTabWidget extends  TabActivity {            

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables    
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost    
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab    
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
        TabWidget tw = getTabWidget(); 


        for (int i = 0; i < tw.getChildCount(); i++) { 
                    View v = tw.getChildAt(i); 
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable 
        (R.drawable.tab_artist)); 
                  } 



        //First tab
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FirstActivity.class);    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost    
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("First")
        .setContent(intent);    
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabselected);

         //Second tab
         intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost    
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator("Second")
            .setContent(intent);    
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
             getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabselected);

             //third
             intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ThirdActivity.class);    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost    
                spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator("Third")
                .setContent(intent);    
                tabHost.addTab(spec);
                getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabselected);

    }
}
```

/*tab_artist.xml*/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
<!-- When selected, use grey -->    
<item android:background="@drawable/tabselected"  android:state_selected="true" />    
<!-- When not selected, use white-->    
<item android:background="@drawable/tabunselected" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class HelloTabWidget extends  TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener{  
.....

mTabHost. setOnTabChangedListener(this);

@Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

              // Here in tabId you will get the name of the Tab from that you can check and set the background 
                // of the requirement tab according to need.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `onTabChangeListener()` and there modify their backgrounds. Cheers

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html

Edit:
Use the tabHost to implement the method. You can implemented where ever you want. Let's say do it after you set all the TabWidgets. Its good practice to use ids of the tab like you've set them "First", "Second" etc etc.

```
 tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
          @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                        if(tabId.equals("First"){
                                //do something
                        }else if(tabId.equals("Second"))
                        {
                            //do something
                        }// etc etc etc


                        }});
```

Comment: Can u plz tell me where and how do i need to use it with some example

Comment: Then accept the answer. That's how this community works :) Cheers. I'mg glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
Tabhost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
@Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

            for(int i=0;i<tb.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
            {
                   tb.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabunselected); //unselected
            }
            tb.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tb.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabselected); 
}});
```